# Where would a file be located on my Node.js + Express server if I send a CSV file to the server using jQuery's ajax method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, express

I am sending a CSV file to my node + express server using jQuery's ajax POST method. When I post the csv file to my express route, I don't know how to access the file once it reaches the server. My goal is to pass the CSV file into my route's middleware called upload.single(). I'm also not sure which data type to specify for the ajax call.

Here is my form where I accept the CSV file:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} encType="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="userFile" type="file" name="userFile"></input>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload New Candidates"></input>
</form>
```

Here is my handleSubmit function which makes the POST request:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var csvToSend = document.getElementById("userFile").files[0];

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
          data: csvToSend,
          success: success,
          dataType: //not sure what to put here
      });
}
```

Here is my express route on the server. How should I access the CSV file sent from the client and enter it into the upload.single() middlware?

```
app.post('/', upload.single('userFile'), function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Comment: When you connect to your server (ssh?  FTP?) what do you see?  Can you find the uploaded file?  Ohhh local host?  Try finder or windows explorer.

Comment: The file makes it to my server if I let the form submit automatically. I just don't know where the file is located in my request if I use jQuery or another HTTP library to send the file.

Comment: Your route syntax suggests using [`multer`](https://npmjs.com/package/multer)? If that is the case, can you please post more of the file containing your `multer` implementation?

Answer (score -1):

As peteb mentioned it looks like you're using multer for a single file and so in that situation:

```js
// If you set up multer to store files locally
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });
const fs = require("fs");

app.post('/', upload.single('userFile'), async function(req, res, next) {
    const filePath = req.file.path;
    const fileData = await fs.promises.readFile(filePath); // Buffer of csv file

    const csvString = fileData.toString();
    // Do whatever you need to with the csv file

    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```